# How to remove non-latest image in Docker?

Tags: docker

I have a docker image for debian where its tag is not `latest`

```
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE    
debian              9.3                 1b3ec9d977fb        12 months ago       100MB
```

When I run:

```
docker rmi debian
```

I get the following:

```
Error: No such image: debian
```

How do I remove this image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debian is the repository. You can remove by repository:tag

`docker rmi debian:9.3`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the docker rmi -f flag to untag/remove images by ID.

```
docker rmi -f 1b3ec9d977fb
```